# Alternative programs to py.exe for running Python

Tags: python

So I have been working in C and C++ for 5 years now and I wanted to start learning Python, but I can't find a similar compiler to Code::Blocks, for example, that can actually tell you if you misspelled a command or something. Is there any compiler that can do that?
Also, I don't really feel comfortable programming in something similar to command prompt. :)

Thanks!

Comment: to help you for your searches you're looking for an "IDE" (Integrated Development Environment") or a "code editor", not really a "compiler"

Comment: You can use a linter like `pylint` to check your code statically.

Comment: You are not looking for a "compiler" instead you are describing an "IDE" of which there are many: PyCharm, VSCode, etc

Comment: python  programs does not have to be compiled. They are run directly from the script file. (the source code).

After installing python in your machine, you can run a program in console like this:

    python script.py